# Сделать кнопку "показать\скрыть"

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/coolerprinter/zf1f2kac/

Код только показывает/раскрывает, не могу сделать, чтобы скрывал содержимое при *клике снова на кнопку*

```
$(".mainbut").click(function(){
    $(".mainbut-menu").animate({bottom: "41px"},500).css({"display":"block"});
});
```

Анимация должна сохраниться, т.е. использовать SlideToggle или SlideDown - не вариант

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  var a = 1,
    b = $(".mainbut-menu");
  $(".mainbut").click(function() {
    a ^= 1;
    b.css({
      display: "block"
    }).animate({
      height: a ? 0 : 360
    }, 500, function() {
      a && b.css({
        display: "none"
      })
    })
  })
});
```

```css
    .mainbut {
      position: absolute;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 10;
      left: 10px;
      bottom: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: .8s;
    }
    .mainbut:hover {
      color: lightskyblue;
    }
    .mainbut-menu {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 41px;
      left: 1px;
      width: 260px;
      height: 0;
      background-color: #666;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      display: none;
    }
    .mainbut-menu .mainbut-element {
      padding: 3px;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: black;
      height: 25px;
      display: block;
    }
    #panel {
      background: black;
      opacity: 0.7;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <p class="mainbut">Show/Close</p>
</div>

<div class="mainbut-menu">
  <p class="mainbut-element"></p>
  <p class="mainbut-element"></p>
  <p class="mainbut-element"></p>
  <p class="mainbut-element"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var opened = false;
$(".mainbut").click(function(){
    if(opened){
        $(".mainbut-menu").animate({bottom: "41px"},500).css({"display":"block"});
    }else{
        //Код, скрывающий меню, например
        $(".mainbut-menu").css({"display":"none"});
    }
    opened = !opened;
});
```